# Remove First and Last double Quotes from "["Morning Shift","Day Shift"]"

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I want to remove First and Last Quotes from this array Using JavaScript:

```
"["Morning Shift","Day Shift"]"
```

**After Remove quotes output look like this**

```
["Morning Shift","Day Shift"]
```

Comment: `'"["Morning Shift","Day Shift"]"'.slice(1,-1)`

Comment: `'"["Morning Shift","Day Shift"]"'.replace(/^"|"$/,'')`

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = `["Morning Shift","Day Shift"]`; 

data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
```